# How to move the first letter of a word to the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to remove the first letter of a word and move it to the end, for example:

```
word = 'whatever'
# I want to convert it to 'hateverw'
```

So far I've tried this:

```
word[1:] # hatever
```

But how should I move the first letter to the end?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use:

```
word[1:]+word[0]
```

Comment: What is this called when you use varaiblename[1:]? I would like to research more about this to find more syntaxing info.

Comment: This is called Python [slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/190597), or just [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did:

```
wrd = input("Give me a word: ")

pig = wrd[1:] + wrd[0] + "ay"

print(wrd, "in Pig Latin it is:", pig.lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

**CODE :**

```
word=input()
print(word[1:]+word[0])
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
>>> oHell
>>> Hello
```

The code (word [1:0]) prints from the second character till the last.

> If you want to write a code to print the first character then write the code as:

```
a="AbC"
print(a[0])
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
>>> A
```

> Because the index of the string always starts from 0 and not 1.